# XML/Java - Creating Two OnClick Methods and RadioButton Writing to Specific Values

Tags: android

This is a Noob question. I am sorry if it has been answered. I have been searching but either could not find or understand the answer. Anyway, I am trying to write a simple weight and balance program for a fleet of aircraft but I'm not sure how to proceed.

I'm trying to figure out how to have the program write to a specific field while a certain radio button is checked.

Could anyone be of any assistance? Thank you!

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_weight_and_balance"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.tropicaircharters.android.employee.weightAndBalance">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Aircraft Currently Selected:"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/aircraft_selected"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="50dp">



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="A" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="B" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="C" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="D" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="E" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="F" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/display_a"
        android:text="@string/a_weight" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/display_b"
        android:text="@string/b_weight" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/display_c"
        android:text="@string/c_weight" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/display_d"
        android:text="@string/d_weight" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/display_e"
        android:text="@string/e_weight" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/display_f"
        android:text="@string/f_weight" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Weight" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/weight_display"
        android:text="@string/weight_display" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="CG" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/cg_display" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="25dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Last Weights Entered" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/last_weight"
            android:id="@+id/display_last_entry_1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/last_weight2"
            android:id="@+id/display_last_entry_2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/last_weight3"
            android:id="@+id/display_last_entry_3"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/last_weight4"
            android:id="@+id/display_last_entry_4" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/last_weight5"
            android:id="@+id/display_last_entry_5"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Fuel Tanks"
            android:gravity="center"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1">



    <TextView
            android:text="Main Tanks"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
            android:text="Auxiliary Tanks"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:text="0 gallons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="0 gallons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:text="0 pounds"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <TextView
                android:text="0 pounds"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:text="Weight in Section" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/radio_section">
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_section_a"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:text="A" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_section_b"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:text="B" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_section_c"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:text="C" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_section_d"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:text="D" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_section_e"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:text="E" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_section_f"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:text="F" />
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/enter_weight_box"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="@string/enter_weight" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_weight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Add Weight"
        android:onClick="add_weight"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Subtract Weight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/subtract_weight"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="subtract_weight" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/change_aircraft"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Change Aircraft"
        android:onClick="change_aircraft"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Calculator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/calculator"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="startActivity(calculator)" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Java

```
package com.tropicaircharters.android.employee;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;

import static android.R.attr.onClick;
import static android.R.id.input;
import static android.icu.lang.UCharacter.GraphemeClusterBreak.T;
import static android.icu.lang.UCharacter.GraphemeClusterBreak.V;
import static     com.tropicaircharters.android.employee.R.id.display_last_entry_1;
import static com.tropicaircharters.android.employee.R.id.subtract_weight;
import static com.tropicaircharters.android.employee.R.string.a_weight;
import static com.tropicaircharters.android.employee.R.string.weight_display;

public class weightAndBalance extends AppCompatActivity {

//These are weights for each section.

int main_tank_gallons = 0;
int main_tank_weight = main_tank_gallons*6;
int aux_tank_gallons = 0;
int aux_tank_weight = aux_tank_gallons*6;


EditText enter_weight_box;


TextView display_a, weight_display, display_last_weight, display_last_weight_2, display_last_weight_3, display_last_weight_4, display_last_weight_5;

Button add_weight, subtract_weight;

RadioButton radio_section_a, radio_section_b, radio_section_c, radio_section_d, radio_section_e, radio_section_f;

double enter_weight, total_weight, a_weight;

String current_section, last_shizzle, last_shizzle2, last_shizzle3, last_shizzle4, last_shizzle5;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_weight_and_balance);

    enter_weight_box = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter_weight_box);
    display_a = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_a);
    weight_display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.weight_display);
    add_weight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_weight);
    subtract_weight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subtract_weight);
    display_last_weight = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_last_entry_1);
    display_last_weight_2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_last_entry_2);
    display_last_weight_3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_last_entry_3);
    display_last_weight_4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_last_entry_4);
    display_last_weight_5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_last_entry_5);

    //This displays adds the entered number to A, the Total,
    // and creates the last weights entered log.
    add_weight.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            enter_weight = Double.parseDouble(enter_weight_box.getText().toString());
            a_weight = a_weight + enter_weight;
            total_weight = total_weight + enter_weight;
            last_shizzle5 = last_shizzle4;
            last_shizzle4 = last_shizzle3;
            last_shizzle3 = last_shizzle2;
            last_shizzle2 = last_shizzle;
            last_shizzle = "Added " + Double.toString(enter_weight) + " in A";



            //These create displays for totals and the last entered log.
            display_a.setText(Double.toString(a_weight));
            weight_display.setText(Double.toString(total_weight));
            display_last_weight.setText(last_shizzle);
            display_last_weight_2.setText(last_shizzle2);
            display_last_weight_3.setText(last_shizzle3);
            display_last_weight_4.setText(last_shizzle4);
            display_last_weight_5.setText(last_shizzle5);
            enter_weight_box.setText("");
        }

    });
    //This displays and subtracts the entered number to A, the Total,
    // and creates the last weights entered log.
    subtract_weight.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            enter_weight = Double.parseDouble(enter_weight_box.getText().toString());
            a_weight = a_weight - enter_weight;
            total_weight = total_weight - enter_weight;
            last_shizzle5 = last_shizzle4;
            last_shizzle4 = last_shizzle3;
            last_shizzle3 = last_shizzle2;
            last_shizzle2 = last_shizzle;
            last_shizzle = "Subtracted " + Double.toString(enter_weight) + " in A";

            //These create displays for totals and the last entered log.
            display_a.setText(Double.toString(a_weight));
            weight_display.setText(Double.toString(total_weight));
            display_last_weight.setText("Subtracted "+Double.toString(enter_weight)+" in "+"A");
            display_last_weight.setText(last_shizzle);
            display_last_weight_2.setText(last_shizzle2);
            display_last_weight_3.setText(last_shizzle3);
            display_last_weight_4.setText(last_shizzle4);
            display_last_weight_5.setText(last_shizzle5);
            enter_weight_box.setText("");
        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: 1) This code doesn't compile. The IDE should tell you why. You cannot have two `onClick` methods on one button. 2) Your second onClick looks the exact same as the first.

Comment: Did you want to `subtract_weight.setOnClickListener`?

Comment: You can also read the documentation how how to handle Radio button click events correctly. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html#HandlingEvents

Comment: @cricket_007 Hey, thanks for the reply. I figured out the subtract button and cleaned things up a bit, but I'm still not sure how to proceed with the radio buttons writing to specific values. 

What do you suppose would be the most straightforward way to do that? i.e. write to double b_weight when b_section radio box is checked.

I updated the code with dropbox links(stackoverflow was getting mad about my code). Thanks!

Comment: Please don't use Dropbox - I don't know why it wouldn't like your code, but you should definitely post it here

Comment: @cricket_007 There we go, think I did something weird at first.

Comment: Okay, so I'm still not sure what you're problem is. You never used `findViewById` to get any RadioButton. That's the first step, then simply check `radioButton.isChecked()`, I think, to decide your actions

Comment: @crick_007

Ok, so I've setup:

    `radio_section_a.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                current_section = "a";
    }`

How could I apply that to the button so it would be like -  (current_section +_weight) = (current_section +_weight) + enter_weight;

Comment: See my comment above. `OnClickListener` is not what you want. You need a compound button click listener to known if the radiobutton gets checked.

Comment: In other words, `setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()` is more correct

Comment: @cricket_007 Sorry if I'm a bit slow and thanks for being patient, I literally knew nothing about code two days ago.

So once I set up `setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()` would I use the `if (checked)` statement to change the method invoked by the add_weight button, nestle the method in below `setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()` or something else entirely?

Thanks again!

Comment: I mean, you don't really need a click listener on the radio button. You can check which radio button is checked within the weight button click listeners.

Comment: Well,let's say I already have the radio buttons all setup to provide this data to a string, `current_selection`.  That will have the value a, b, or c, etc.  How can I tell the computer that I now want to modify the value in string `a_weight` or `b_weight`, etc when I press add weight or subtract weight. based on what is in string `current_selection`?

Comment: that is, if `current_selection` is currently a, I want it to modify `a_weight`. if `current_selection` is b, i want to modify b_weight by what is in the enter text box

Comment: Is there a way I can just set some kind equation in as part of the button like `(@string/current_selection+_weight) = EnterText + (@string/current_selection+_weight)` so I would get `a_weight = EnterText + a_weight` if the current value of `current_selection` was a

Comment: Figured it out with `if`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Cool. Feel free to provide your solution below